# screen capture with frame

Tags: ios

if you want to capture the screen is ios app , you can use the following codes:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
currentCaptureImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but I want to capture the picture from a specific point, e.g. (start.x, start.y) and with a specific width and height, how can I do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just google it and got best answer From [How to capture a specific size of the self.view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692611/how-to-capture-a-specific-size-of-the-self-view:-)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(300, 320), YES, 0.);
    [self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If your view was, for example, 600x320 and you wanted to capture the middle 300 points in width, you'd translate the context 150 points to the left:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(300, 320), YES, 0.);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -150.f, 0.f);
    [self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```